# Como escolher o tipo de data mais adequado no código?

Tags: c#, .net, data, datetime, tipagem

Como escolher entre `DateTime`, `DateOnly`, `DateTimeOffset`, `TimeSpan` e `TimeOnly`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviamente que alguns são só para data e só para horário, se você precisa de um ou outro deve escolher isso antes de tudo.

Vamos entender que esses tipos servem para duas coisas: um ponto na linha do tempo, ou seja, ele indica um momento específico na história universal, um marco de algum acontecimento qualquer, da mesma forma que tem um marco de quilometragem em uma estrada; ou determina uma quantidade de tempo, da mesma forma que tem quantos quilômetros foram percorridos em uma viagem.

Sem entender bem essa diferença você não pode trabalhar corretamente com tempos.

E entenda que uma data é uma grandeza diferente na linha do tempo com regras diferentes, mas não deixa de ser um marco no tempo, não importa se é dia ou hora.

## [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

Vamos começar pelo `TimeSpan` que é sobre a quantidade de tempo. É o único tipo para este fim contido no .NET padrão. Ele é fácil de entender e deveria ser usado em muitos casos que as pessoas acham que deve usar o `DateTime`.

Mesmo que a quantidade de tempo que você tenha seja tão grande que tenha dias, meses ou até anos, ele é o correto se o que você tem é essa quantidade de tempo. Não importa se quer computar se passou, ou leve, que dura, quanto demora, etc., de uma fração de segundos da execução de uma aplicação, ou o tempo em horas que um carro ficou em um estacionamento, ou se são os possíveis 4 anos de um curso em uma faculdade. Tudo é quantidade de tempo e pode ser representado com o `TimeSpan`.

Podemos dizer que ele é um intervalo de tempo entre dois pontos da linha do tempo. Por isso uma subtração de dois pontos na linha de tempo dá um `TimeSpan`. Assim como só pode adicionar o `TimeSpan` a um ponto na linha dos tempo, dando outro ponto na linha do tempo. O termo mais correto é uma duração.

Note que intervalo aqui não é o mesmo de faixa de tempo, que são dois pontos distintos na linha do tempo, mas relacionados. O .NET não tem um tipo padrão para isto. A biblioteca [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) tem um tipo assim chamado [`Interval`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Ele pode até mesmo estar com início e/ou fim em aberto.

Para a NodaTime o equivalente do `TimeSpan` é o tipo `Duration`. [Ver mais](https://nodatime.org/3.1.x/userguide/arithmetic).

Algumas pessoas escolhem usar o `Duration` quando todo o resto vem da NodaTime. Em alguns casos pode ser interessante usar um [`Period`](https://nodatime.org/3.1.x/api/NodaTime.Period.html) dela para representar uma quantidade de tempo. Veja a diferença entre eles na [documentação](https://nodatime.org/userguide/arithmetic).

Escolher a NodaTime é bem interessante, tem uma biblioteca moderna e mais bem pensada, mas tem dificuldades com o .NET e principalmente com outras bibliotecas que não entendem seus tipos.

No passado algumas pessoas usavam o `TimeSpan` para marcar o horário de um dia (um ponto na linha do tempo), mas isso é um erro, ainda que pudesse funcionar em certas situações. Hoje tem tipo melhor para isto.

## [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

Agora vamos falar dos tipos em uma linha no tempo, começando pelo tipo mais tradicional, que marca não só o ano (com século), mês, e dia, mas também o momento exato do dia, com hora, minuto, segundo, e fração de segundo.

Em muitos casos ele era usado com a parte do horário todo zerado, e embora funcionasse em muitas situações, não era adequado.

Equivocadamente ele pode ter o tempo em representações diferentes através de um dado [`Kind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que indica se o horário é local (fuso horário que o sistema indicar); Utc (o horário padrão considerado neutro, ou sem um fuso específico, e que em alguns casos é o mesmo do GMT (o horário de Londres), mas pode não ser, e muitos programadores quebram a cara por isso; ou ainda pode ser tipo de tempo não especificado.

A NodaTime tem tipos separados para lidar com isso, não vou entrar neles aqui, mas pode consultar a documentação. Isso é mais sensato, e um dos maiores motivos para ela existir.

Note que não tem qual é o fuso horário adotado na linha do tempo. Note também que o mesmo número pode representar pontos diferentes na linha do tempo dependendo do `Kind` adotado. Se você "gravar" um horário local na região de Brasília sem horário de verão ou qualquer outro evento que afete o fuso, e mandar ler como se ele fosse UTC, então dará resultados diferentes. O ideal é não misturar nunca, nunca mesmo nem dentro em qualquer parte da aplicação, ou até mesmo fora. Se for usar o dado fora precisa saber se necessita fazer alguma conversão.

Em geral se você nunca trabalha com fusos, o local pode ser adequado, senão o UTC costuma ser melhor. E onde tem horário de verão tem fusos diferentes mesmo em uma única região.

O local pode funcionar bem quando o que está registrado é só o horário local mesmo, sem ter uma representação exata na linha do tempo. Por exemplo marcou 17:00:00 e não importa que fuso está, se é horário de verão, só interessa que são 5 da tarde em algum lugar quando aquilo aconteceu, mais nada. Na troca de horário de verão por exemplo pode ter dois pontos na linha do tempo completamente diferentes e ambos serem 00:00:00. O UTC não é ambíguo.

Ele funciona com compatibilidade com dados externos, como de banco de dados, que tenham as mesmas características, ter a parte de data, de hora, até fracionada e ter se é local ou UTC. O mais comum externamente é usar UTC. Por isso pode ser interessante preferir ele em toda a aplicação.

Ele funciona bem se o programador entender que no momento de apresentar deve considerar o fuso do usuário. Representação é diferente do valor real. O mesmo dado pode ser apresentado para usuários diferentes, ou até mesmo o mesmo usuário em momentos diferentes, com valores que parecem diferentes, mas é o mesmo ponto na linha do tempo. Tudo depende da sua aplicação. Aqui por exemplo não apresenta o horário de acordo com o local onde estou, ele só considera UTC.

Como já dito antes, se subtrair dois deles dá um `TimeSpan` e não outro `DateTime`. Assim como só pode adicionar um `TimeSpan` em um deles para dar outro `DateTime`. No lugar do `TimeSpan` pode usar alguns outros tipos com quantidades, por exemplo pode usar métodos prontos para adicionar uma quantidade inteira de meses ou dias, ou horas ou segundos. Essa quantidade não deixa de ser um intervalo de tempo de forma mais simplificada que o `TimeSpan`.

## [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

É o mesmo que o `DateTime`, mas ele tem a informação quase completa do fuso horário, ou seja, é o ponto na linha do tempo e o deslocamento que deve considerar em relação ao fuso UTC. Então se formos usar o horário local de Brasília com horário de verão ele tem um deslocamento -0200, ou seja, menos duas horas exatas.

Ele consome mais recursos, mas dá uma informação mais exata. É pouco usado, mas é útil quando lida com dados diversos com fusos diferentes.

Não é um tipo perfeito, e novamente, pra isso existe a NodaTime. Em geral dá para usar, mas é preciso mais cuidado, o conceito não é tão bom quanto o adotado na NodaTime. Para informação completa ela usa o [`ZonedDateTime`](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/api/NodaTime.ZonedDateTime.html).

## [`DateOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

Este é um tipo novo e parece bem fácil de entender. Ele só tem a data (ano com século, mês e dia).

A não ser por compatibilidade com algo antigo deve usar sempre que não for importante a parte horária do dia.

Há casos que o dado externo, como de banco de dados, tem justamente só isso, então ele é mais compatível.

## [`TimeOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

O nome já diz o básico e visto o anterior fica óbvio qual é a recomendação.

Ele guarda qual é o momento na linha do tempo dentro de um dia qualquer, um tempo passado ao longo de um dia, ou seja, pode ser qualquer dia, isso não importa. Ele vai de 00:00:00.0000000 à 23:59:59.9999999.

Não confundir, novamente, com uma quantidade de tempo que poderia ser até maior que 24 horas.

No passado usava-se um `DateTime` com uma data básica, em geral o dia 01 de janeiro do ano 1. Não era nada bom. Tinha quem usava o `TimeSpan`, mas era só por falta de algo mais correto.

Ele não tem qualquer informação sobre fuso horário, nem mesmo o `Kind`. Pode ser complicado o usar em conjunto com um `DateTime`, por isso não é sempre uma escolha óbvia e se tiver que usá-lo em algum momento para conjugar com uma data, terá que observar sobre o fuso horário.

## Mais da NodaTime

Ela tem vários outros tipos, mexe melhor com calendários, e tem tipos para indicar um conjunto de ano e mês ou de mês e dia.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).